# How Generate XLSX using powershell

Tags: powershell

We are planning to generate XLSX format to generate a report using powershell.
we are able to CSV format , but we are unable to add colors in csv file.

Can any please help how to generate XLSX using powershell?

Answer (score 1):

There's a script created by [Peter Kriegel](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/peter%20kriegel/) on the TechNet Gallery that does this. You could simply leverage Peter's script or tweak it to suit your needs. The script is listed here:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-XLSX-PowerShell-f2f0c035